# Lucene search to find either of 2 particular content model types within a folder

Tags: javascript, lucene, alfresco, web-scripting

I am trying to write a lucene search in an Alfresco webscript (javascript) to find 1 of 2 custom types within a custom type cm:folder

So the folder might have the following contents
1. Some text (cm:content)
2. More text (custom:content)
3. Even more text (custom:content)
4. Another folder (cm:folder)
5. Crazy, more text (custom:content2)
6. Last text (custom:content2)

The expected result of the lucene search should return the following
2. More text (custom:content)
3. Even more text (custom:content)
5. Crazy, more text (custom:content2)
6. Last text (custom:content2)

Where am I going wrong with the lucene search?  I have written something along the lines of

```
+PATH:"/app:company_home/PATH_TO_A_CUSTOM_TYPE_FOLDER/*" TYPE:"custom:content1"  TYPE:"custom:content2"
```

The problem is it returns all content, I think the intention is to write something like

```
+PATH:"/app:company_home/PATH_TO_A_CUSTOM_TYPE_FOLDER/*" +TYPE:"custom:content1" OR +PATH:"/app:company_home/PATH_TO_A_CUSTOM_TYPE_FOLDER/*"+TYPE:"custom:content2"
```

Worse case scenario is I can run 2 lucene searches, but it would be good to know how the query is written :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do the following:

```
+PATH:"/app:company_home/PATH_TO_A_CUSTOM_TYPE_FOLDER/*" AND (TYPE:"custom:content1" TYPE:"custom:content2")
```

Because if you write +PATH TYPE: TYPE:, it actually says PATH:(Must have) OR TYPE: OR TYPE:, hence it looks that if the PATH: is matched it will return everything beneath.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example I tried **+PATH:"/app:company_home/xy:folderABC/*" AND (TYPE:"xy:{http://www.companyXY.com/model/content/1.0}folder")**. In my case I've checked that in the content-model the xy:folder type is used.